# Commit DataGrid data to database?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I would like to save the data in this datagrid to my database.
Currently I am using entity framework to interact with my database.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ModelListe}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding actv_phase}" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Component" Width="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding actv_name}" CanUserReorder="False" Header="Question" Width="300" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Could you provide some C# code to get better response please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change something on `DataGrid` it changes your objects too. So put `Button` on your form with following code:

```
private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

Click the button when you are done changing.